# how to calculate the range of two independent distribution with given pdf

Tags: probability, statistics

Given two statistically independent random variable X and Y, where $ X  $ follows a distribution of $ f_X(x)$ having range $[x_{min}, x_{max}]$ and $Y$ follows a distribution of $f_Y(y)$ having range $[-1, 1]$ then what is the pdf of its product of two distribution $Z = XY$ and what is the range ?
From [the product distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_distribution)  I got the pdf of Z but how to get its range ?

Here the pdf of $X$ is $f_X(x) = \frac{2x^{-\frac{m+4}{m +2}}}{(m + 2)r_e^2}, x \in [x_{min}, x_{max}]$ and the pdf of $Y$ is $f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\pi\sqrt{1 - y^2}}, y \in [-1, 1]$ I want to find the pdf of Z = XY which is $f_Z(z)$  Here $r_e, m$ are some constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any particular real number $t$ (positive, negative, or zero) if it is multiplied by something in $[-1,1]$ the result can be any number in the interval $[-|t|,|t|].$ then if $t$ itself is varied in $[x_{min},x_{max}],$ it follows the overall result of the product varies in the interval $[-a,a]$ where $a$ is the maximum of the absolute values of $x_{min}$ and $x_{max}$

It looks like you already know how to form the relevant pdf for the product.